# CakePHP REST + AngularJS - How to send Access Denied response in JSON?

Tags: php, json, angularjs, rest, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and am using version 2.7.5.

I followed the tutorial to create a basic REST service.

I now secured them using the basic auth tutorial.

Now, I have an AngularJS app over this REST service but need a way to prompt users to login or say their account does not have access to that resource.

Right now, when the REST call is made, and they do not have access, the response is a redirect HTML page to "/" or to logon. But I want the response in JSON with a message that says "access denied" or "session is up please logon.." etc.

I know it's the flash variable in cakephp but i am using AngularJS.

So my question is, where do I code in cakephp to send json response instead of HTML page redirect if a user does not have access to a certain rest url after logging in?

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a response header back to the request with the correct status code(401).

```
if(!$authorized){
    return header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
}
```

You can catch the error code in your request method, for example an ajax request

```
.error(status){
    switch(status.code)
    {
        case 401:
            //Unauthorized
        break;
    }
}
```